# Calculate elapse time in java

Tags: java

I have timestamps like below and need to calculate elapse time.

```
t1: 2014-11-07 11:22:39.854296-08
t2: 2014-11-07 11:22:52.748804-08
```

I use the following code but the result is not correct:

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"); 

        String time1 = "2014-11-07 11:22:39.854296-08";
        java.util.Date parsedDate1 = dateFormat.parse(time1);

        String time2 = "2014-11-07 11:22:52.748804-08";
        java.util.Date parsedDate2 = dateFormat.parse(time2);

        int elapse = (int)(parsedDate2.getTime() - parsedDate1.getTime());
```

If I use format: ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"), the result is correct.

Comment: Calculating the difference between two times/dates is NEVER done by subtracting them, there are just two many factors involved. If you're using Java 8, makes use of the new time API or use Joda Time

Comment: also, would the `elapse` be int or `double` ? methinks, double

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021)

Comment: @Coffee It should be `long`...

Comment: Or [perhaps this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328912/java-getting-time-interval/13329218#13329218)

Comment: @John how did you got these timestamps.??

Comment: From log of database.